# How to find special values in large file using C++ or C

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, file

I've some values I want to find in a large (> 500 MB) text file using C++ or C. I know that a possible matching value can only exist at the very beginning of each line and its length is exactly ten characters. Okay, I can read the whole file line by line searching the value with substr() or use regexp but that is a little bit ugly and very slow. I consider to use a embedded database (e.g. Berkeley DB) but the file I want to search in is very dynamic and I see a problem to bring it into the database every time. Due to a limit of memory it is not possible to load the whole file at once into memory. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What code have you written, and where did you run into trouble?  

(and don't tag a question both [C] and [C++].  They are different languages)

Comment: I'd consider whether something like AWK or even grep might not be the right tool for the job. What you've described will almost certainly be I/O bound, so you're unlikely to gain much from using C or C++ (and could just about as easily lose as gain).

Comment: Line lengths are not fixed, are they?

Comment: No, line lengths are not fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem well suited to C/C++. Since the problem is defined with the need to parse whole lines of text, and perform pattern matching on the first 10-chars, something interpreted, such as python or perl would seem to be simpler.

How about:

```
import os
pattern ='0123456789'   # <-- replace with pattern

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(pattern):
            print "Eureka!'
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `egrep -q '^0123456789' myfile.txt && echo "Eureka"`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you're going to do this faster than using the stdio library, reading each line in turn into a buffer, and using `strchr`, `strcmp`, `strncmp` or some such. Given the description of your problem, that's already fairly optimal. There's no magic that will avoid the need to go through the file line by line looking for your pattern.

That said, regular expressions are almost certainly not needed here if you're dealing with a fixed pattern of exactly ten characters at the start of a line -- *that* would be needlessly slow and I wouldn't use the regex library.

If you really, really need to beat the last few microseconds out of this, and the pattern is literally constant and at the start of a line, you might be able to do a `memchr` on read-in buffers looking for "\npattern" or some such (that is, including the newline character in your search) but you make it sound like the pattern is not precisely constant. Assuming it is not precisely constant, the most obvious method (see first paragraph) is the the most obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of values that you are looking for then you want to use [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).  This algorithm allows you to create a single finite state machine that can search for all occurrences of any string in a set simultaneously.  This means that you can search through your file a single time and find all matches of every value you are looking for.  The wikipedia link above has a link to a C implementation of Aho-Corasick.  If you want to look at a Go implementation that I've written you can look [here](https://github.com/runningwild/stringz/blob/master/core/aho_corasick.go).

If you are looking for a single or a very small number of values then you'd be better off using [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).  Although in this case you might want to just use grep, which will probably be just as fast as anything you write for this application.

Answer (score 0):

How about using memory mapped files before search?

http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html

One way may be loading and searching for say first 64 MB in memory, unload this then load the next 64 MB and so on (in multiples of 4 KB so that you are not overlooking any text which might be split at the block boundary)

Also view Boyer Moore String Search

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done fast.  Been there. Done that.  It is easy to introduce bugs, however.

The trick is in managing end of buffer, since you will read a buffer full of data, search that buffer, and then go on to the next.  Since the pattern could span the boundary between two buffers, you wind up writing most of your code to cover that case.

At any rate, outside of the boundary case, you have a loop that looks like the following:

```
unsigned short *p = buffer;
while( (p < EOB) && ( patterns[*p] ) ) ++p;
```

This assumes that EOB has been appropriately initialized, and that patterns[] is an array of 65536 values which are 0 if you can't be at the start of your pattern and 1 if you can.

Depending on your CR/LF and byte order conventions, patterns to set to 1 might include \nx or \rx where x is the first character in your 10 character pattern.  Or x\n or x\r for the other byte order.  And if you don't know the byte order or convention you can include all four.

Once you have a candidate location (EOL followed by the first byte) you do the work of checking the remaining 9 bytes.  Building the patterns array is done offline, ahead of time.  Two byte patterns fit in a small enough array that you don't have too much memory thrashing when doing the indexing, but you get to zip through the data twice as fast as if you did single byte.

There is one crazy optimization you can add into this, and that is to write a sentinel at the end of buffer, and put it in your patterns array.  But that sentinel must be something that couldn't appear in the file otherwise.  It gets the loop down to one test, one lookup and one increment, though.